# ReactJS without IDE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a look at reactJS. 
Unfortunately all the tutorials I found assume, that I have an IDE. But I don't want to install an IDE just for this purpose and I even can't do that in my working place.

So I am wondering, how I can use React without an IDE. Just by injecting the necessary library-files. I don't care, if it is working slower than otherwise, I just want to get it to work.

JSbin and Co are only secondbest choices, because I want to store the written files for later of course.

Does anyone know a tutorial, that describes, which libraries I have to inject and how I can get the first steps?

I hope, someone can help. Regards

Christian

Btw, my actual attempt looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>React</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="react-container"></div>


<script type="text/jsx">

var meineKomponente = React.createClass({
    render: function() {    
        return <h1>Hallo Welt</h1>;
    }
});

React.render(<meineKomponente />,  document.querySelector('#react-container'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The information for this is gathered from different places and of course, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you mean transpilation, you just need Node and npm (for the build and dependencies, respectively). The text editor you use is irrelevant, although some provide niceties when dealing with React (linting, highlighting, etc.). Also, parsing the JSX during runtime is not optimal.

Comment: There is actually no reason to not use an IDE since most of them are free anyways.

Comment: @MuratK."I even can't do that in my working place"

Comment: You can't go wrong with Vim. Simply create the necessary files and folders. This will require setting up with some sort of bundler that can consume the jsx files and output vanilla javascript.

Comment: @MuratK: Of course there is a reason for not using an IDE: 
I Can not install anything in my working place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some browser-based IDEs.

- StackBlitz -- https://stackblitz.com/ -- only heard about this recently, so haven't actually used it, but it seems real nice. As a bonus, it has a quick start template for ReactJS projects, which might be exactly what you're looking for.
- Cloud9: https://c9.io/ -- Always a solid choice.

There's more, I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks, that's, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any specific IDE to use a library or framework. You can use notepad, or textedit and achieve the same results.

The question is, why would you not use an IDE? Code completion, automatic linting, and a near-infinite number of useful plugins are all at your disposal if you go the IDE route.

As far as tutorials go, Facebook's own React docs have a great tutorial which covers all of the basics: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

If you're concerned that they're using ES6, you could use JSFiddle to see what's gone wrong:

https://jsfiddle.net/tt6uet4a/1/

```
var MeineKomponente = React.createClass({
    render: function() {    
        return <h1>Hallo Welt</h1>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MeineKomponente name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

As far as your code goes, you'll need to use ReactDOM's render function, as well as uppercasing your JSX element name.

Answer (score 0):

To develop React, you do not need an IDE. All you need is a terminal and a text editor. 
I assume that you are thinking React as a javascript library like jQuery, that's why you are including `React` to a `script` inside `head` tag like "old-school" javascript.

For a simple start with React, I think you should first have a look at [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/). Try to install it, then follow [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).